# How to install OpenERP on Mac OS X Mavericks?

Tags: python, macos, postgresql, odoo, openerp-7

I want to install OpenERP v7 on Mac OS X. How can I install it?

I tried to install it  `brew install postgresql` I succeed to install postgresql but when I create the user with following command `createuser openerp`I got the error like
`createuser:command not found` I also got an error when I type `psql`.

Comment: what have you tried so far,what problems did you face,minimum code for explaining the exact problem? kindly provide all these

Comment: i am trying to edit from the openoffice but it's print nthing

Comment: do you use rml or xml reports?

Comment: hi CZoellner how to use payslip_line value in seprate box in table in report

Comment: one question after another. and it would help if you give us more specific details on what you're doing and how you're doing it. we aren't clairvoyants ;-)

Comment: I'm tempted to only leave "I want to install openerp v7 on Mac OS X. How can I install it?" in this question as there's no real informative content in the rest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Install PostgreSQL
2. Create a user for OpenERP
3. Install all dependencies for Python, using `brew` or MacPorts
4. Download OpenERP and extract it
5. Run the following command: `cd openerp; python openerp-server`

Answer (score 6):

Note: OpenERP is now called Odoo.

1. Make sure you have [brew](http://brew.sh) installed.
2. `brew install postgresql`
3. `postgres -D /usr/local/var/postgres` or `launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.postgresql.plist`
4. `createdb odootest`  (not really needed if you use sample data)
5. `git clone https://github.com/odoo/odoo.git`, the repo is 500MB big so this takes a while
6. `cd odoo`
7. `git checkout origin/7.0` switch to 7.0 branch (this should be a better command because it leaves me in detached head, please edit)
8. `sudo python setup.py install`, this will also install many dependencies with `easy_install`, ignore all the warnings
9. `python openerp-server -s` to start with sample data generated by odoo. If you

I also had to `sudo easy_install pyPdf` but I'm not sure if that's because I first tried the master branch. If you experience errors for missing libraries simply `easy_install` them.